# Youtube Data API V3 - Unable to fetch mostPopular youtube videos from android app with restricted API key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In my Android app, I am trying to fetch the most popular youtube videos for a particular region using Youtube Data API V3, which does not require OAuth.

**But getting the below exception** :

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden
>        {
>        "code" : 403,
>        "errors" :                                                                     [ {
>        "domain" : "usageLimits",
>        "message" : "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is 
>   sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
>        "reason" : "ipRefererBlocked",
>        "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=653745488165"
>        } ],
>        "message" : "The request did not specify any Android package name or signing-certificate fingerprint. Please ensure that the client is 
>   sending them or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
>        }

I could not find any API to send or attach package name or signing-certificate fingerprint with the request.

I generated the API key for my android application in google developer console and resticted the API key to my app by specifying
the package name of my app and SHA-1 fingerprint of my apk's keystore file.

**Code snippet used to fetch mostPopular videos** :

```
sYoutube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {

            }
        }).setApplicationName(/*package name of my application here*/>).build();
list = sYoutube.videos().list("snippet,contentDetails");
list.setChart("mostPopular");
list.setMaxResults(3);
list.setRegionCode("IN");
list.setKey(/*API key generated in google developers console*/);
VideoListResponse response = list.execute();
```

But if I remove the restrictions of the API key,I am able to fetch the videos without any error. But I dont want to remove the
API key restrictions.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No idea how to fix it.